# CSS: position absolute varying the div width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having the following div structure in a part of my site. There are two divs one below another. The first div is divided into two elements. One div (**63%**) and a button.

Below this, there is another div which is having same **63% as width and position as absolute.**

Having the position as absolute not resulting in the two divs with the same width in the same size.

A part of CSS code

```
#two{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 63%;
  position: absolute; //Enabling this resulting in varying size even width  is same
}
```

This is my code pen link, https://codepen.io/JGSpark/pen/bZyvEV?editors=1100

I would like to have two divs in the same size as the position absolute. Is there something I can try out here?

Comment: As I  can see you're using width in `%` to the second div you have `width: 63%`  instead of this use ` width: 62.5%;` and add parent di which contain have relative property. or simple add body{ margin:0;} default 8px its taking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We able to add parent div with position:relative. Or Just add position:relative to body tag.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
<div id="one" class="row">
    <div id="textValue"><span id="text">ONE Inner text</span><span id="icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span></div>    
  <button id="template" class="btn primary">Template</button>
</div>
  <div id="two">TWO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you add `position: absolute` *not relative to any element* it is positioned relative to the root element.

A 63% `textValue` is 63% of `#one` element but 63% of `#two` is 63% of the document which *includes the default `body` margin*. So reset this to zero:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* added */
}

#template {
  width: 30%;
}

#textValue {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 63%;
  float: left;
}

#icon {
  width: 5%;
}

#text {
  width: 95%;
  float: left;
}

#one {
  width: 100%;
}

#two {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 63%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="row">
  <div id="textValue"><span id="text">ONE Inner text</span><span id="icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span></div>
  <button id="template" class="btn primary">Template</button>
</div>
<div id="two">TWO</div>
```

Or you can add a wrapper to the element which has `position: relative` - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative; /* added */
}

#template {
  width: 30%;
}

#textValue {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 63%;
  float: left;
}

#icon {
  width: 5%;
}

#text {
  width: 95%;
  float: left;
}

#one {
  width: 100%;
}

#two {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 63%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one" class="row">
    <div id="textValue"><span id="text">ONE Inner text</span><span id="icon "><i class="fa fa-angle-up "></i></span></div>
    <button id="template" class="btn primary ">Template</button>
  </div>
  <div id="two">TWO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Position absolute need to be relative to something, in this case it is relative to the document which has default margin and padding. Try this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one" class="row">
    <div id="textValue"><span id="text">ONE Inner text</span><span id="icon"><i 
class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span></div>    
  <button id="template" class="btn primary">Template</button>
</div>

  <div id="two">TWO</div>
</div>
```

in css add:

```
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the #textValue that is inside #one is 63% that is 63% of #one div.[image]
where as the #two div is given absolute without giving a parent element position relative so it is taking relative to body element that is comparatively bigger than the #one div so 
you able to see the difference even though you have given a same width.